# How to solve this equation in radicals?

Tags: special-functions, roots, radicals, golden-ratio

How to solve the equation $x^6-2\varphi^5x^5+2\varphi x+\varphi^6=0$ in radicals? where $\varphi = \phi^{1/4}$ and $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: Are you sure the polynomial is not homogeneous in $x$ and $\varphi$? The homogeneous version can indeed be factored over $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)$.

Comment: Also, $x=1$ is a solution of this inhomogeneous equation, therefore it is not irreducible. This is not necessarily a show-stopper, but please re-check. Giving some background might help prevent further skepticism.

Comment: @ccorn: I finally figured out what was wrong with this equation. The variable should have been $\varphi = \phi^{1/4} = G_5$. Then $x = G_{125}$. See this recent similar [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241870/) the OP asked.

Comment: Related to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843054/ramanujan-class-invariant-g-125-and-g-5) post and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Schlaefli modular equation,
$$\bigg(\frac{u}{v}\bigg)^3+\bigg(\frac{v}{u}\bigg)^3=2 \bigg(u^2v^2-\frac{1}{u^2v^2}\bigg)$$
or expanded out as a sextic,

> $$u^6 - 2 u^5 v^5 + 2 u v + v^6 = 0\tag1$$

has the closed-form solution,
$$u = G_{25n},\quad v = G_n$$
with *Ramanujan G-function* $G_n$. For rational $n>0$, then $u,v$ are radicals. Courtesy of [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625) by G. Manco, it turns out $(1)$ belongs to that ***special class of sextics that can be solved by quintics*** (similar to how quartics can be solved by cubics).

Given $v = G_n$ in $(1)$, an alternative closed-form solution for $u$ is then,

> $$u=G_{25n}= \frac{(G_n)^5}{10}\Big((\beta+1)(x+1)^2-5\Big)\tag2$$

where $x$ is the real root of the solvable [DeMoivre quintic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/deMoivresQuintic.html),
$$x^5-5\alpha x^3+5\alpha ^2 x -\alpha (\alpha ^2-2\alpha +8)=0$$
and,
$$\alpha =\frac{2\,G_{n}}{(G_{n/25})^5},\quad \beta= \frac{2\,G_{n/25}}{(G_n)^5}$$
For example, knowing just $G_1 = 1,\; G_{1/5}=G_5 = \phi^{1/4},\; G_{25} = \phi$, then $(2)$ is an iterative method to express in radicals ***all*** $G_n$ with $n=5^m$ in terms of the golden ratio $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

G125 is here!I used a 25th order modular equation (Notebook n.2 ch. xix p.231

[image]

Comment: What does "Notebook n.2 ch. xix p.231" mean?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: I assume he means _Ramanujan's Notebooks_.