# Ramanujan's Class Invariant $G_{625}$

Tags: special-functions, radicals, golden-ratio, modular-function

How to calculate the  Ramanujan Class Invariant $G_{625}$?

Equation is:

$x^6-2\varphi^5x^5+2\varphi x+\varphi^6=0$.

$\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: Similar posts: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843054/ramanujan-class-invariant-g-125-and-g-5) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967077/how-to-solve-this-equation-in-radicals).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wish to give another form for $G_{625}$ that I found using Ramanujan's modular equation of the 25th order. Let $G_{25} = \varphi$ with golden ratio $\varphi$, then,

$$\frac{2\,G_{625}}{(G_{25})^5}+1=\frac{1}{\varphi^3}\left(1+(4\varphi)^{1/5}\Big(\big(3+\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}+\big(3-\frac{5^{1/4}}{\varphi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}\Big)\right)^2$$

It seems very elegant!

Along with this expression I'd like to write the inverse:

$$\frac{2  G_{25}^{5}} {G_{625}} – 1=\varphi^{3}\left(1-(\frac{4} {\varphi} )^{1/5}\Big(\big(3+5^{1/4}\varphi^{3/2}\big)^{1/5}+\big(3-5^{1/4} \varphi^{3/2}\big)^{1/5}\Big)\right)^{2}$$

---

*Method*: Squaring

$$5\frac{w(q^{25})}{w(q)} = 1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v}$$

we have

$$5\frac{w^2(q^{25})}{w^2(q^{5})} 5\frac{w^2(q^{5})}{w^2(q)} = \big(1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v} \big)^2$$

Or

$$5\frac{w^2(q^{25})}{w^2(q^{5})} = \frac15\frac{w^2(q)}{w^2(q^5)}  \big(1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v} \big)^2$$

But the modular equation of 5th degree has the expression

$$\frac{w^2(q)}{w^2(q^{5})}=1+2\frac{G_{n}}{(G_{25n})^5}=\frac {5} {1+2\frac{G_{25n}} {(G_{n})^5}}\tag{1}$$

Set

$$(uv)^\frac 1 5=\frac {5}{\frac {w^2(q)}{w^2(q^5)}}-1=2\frac{G_{25n}} {(G_{n})^5}=x$$

and $y=(x-1)^2+7,\;\Delta=y^2-4x^3=(x-4)^2(x^2+4),\,$ hence

$$u=\frac x 2(y+\sqrt \Delta),\quad v=\frac x 2(y-\sqrt \Delta)$$

Since $w(q)$ has $q = e^{\pi i\sqrt{-n}}$, then using $(1)$,

> $$1+2\frac{G_{625n}}{(G_{25n})^5}=\frac 1 5\Big(1+2\frac{G_{n}} {(G_{25n})^5}\Big)\big(1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v} \big)^2\tag2$$

Since $G_1 = 1,\; G_{1/5}=G_5 = \varphi^{1/4},\; G_{5^2} = \varphi$, then $(2)$ is an iterative method to express in radicals ***all*** $G_{5^m}$ in terms of the golden ratio $\varphi$.

---

$\color{green}{Added}$ (by TP):

And a similar one found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1013751/4781) also by Manco for $G_{125}$. Let $G_{5} = \varphi^{1/4}$, then

$$\frac{2\,G_{125}}{(G_{5})^5}+1=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\left(1+(4/\varphi)^{1/5}\Big( \big(4-\sqrt{5}+\frac{5^{3/4}}{\phi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}+\big(4-\sqrt{5}-\frac{5^{3/4}}{\phi^{3/2}}\big)^{1/5}\Big)\right)^2$$

These two were derived from an entry in Notebook 2, Chapter XIX, Entry 12 (iii). (Also in Berndt's *Ramanujan's Notebooks*, Vol III, Entry 12(iii), p.269.) Given the *Jacobi theta function* $\vartheta_3(0,q)=w(q)$. Then,
$$5\frac{w(q^{25})}{w(q)} = 1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v}$$
where,
$$uv = \left(5\frac{w^2(q^5)}{w^2(q)}-1\right)^5$$
$$u+v = \left(5\frac{w^2(q^5)}{w^2(q)}-1\right)\left(11-20\frac{w^2(q^5)}{w^2(q)}+25\frac{w^4(q^5)}{w^4(q)} \right)$$

Comment: Notebook n.2, chapter XIX, Entry 12(iii): http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/notebookindex.htm

Comment: +1. But how did you get from a ratio of theta functions of form $\displaystyle \frac{w(q^{25})}{w(q)}$ to a ratio of eta functions of form $\displaystyle \frac{G_{25n}}{(G_n)^5}$? Kindly complete the edited answer above.

Comment: Squaring $5\frac{w(q^{25})}{w(q)} = 1+\sqrt[5]{u}+\sqrt[5]{v}$

Comment: and applying a modular equation of the 5th order with ratio of eta functions.

Comment: Ah, very clever, so that's how you did it. By the way, you can accept your own answer. Also, a tip: use two dollar signs to center your equations when it is needed. Looks better that way.

Comment: I agree! By the way, $q=e^{-\pi \sqrt{n}}$

Comment: Oh, yes. By the way, you should click on the "accept" button so this question will go off the unanswered list.

Comment: I corrected the typo. I finally found the correct volume and page in Berndt's books and added the details to the post.

Comment: Do you know an elegant relation between $G_n$ and $G_{4n}$? I know one, but it is relatively ugly.

Comment: $(G_{4n})^4=(g_{n} G_{n})^2(G_{n}^4+g_{n}^4)=\frac {1} {4(g_{n} G_{n})^6(G_{n}^4-g_{n}^4)}$

Comment: I am not sure that @TitoPiezasIII saw the formula left 3 days after without the @ so I am leaving this comment here.

Answer (score 4):

The Ramanujan $G_n$ and $g_n$ functions can be computed in *Mathematica* using the *Dedekind eta function*. Let $\tau=\sqrt{-n}$, then,
$$G_n=\frac{2^{-1/4}\,\eta^2(\tau)}{\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)\,\eta(2\tau)}\quad \text{odd}\; n$$
$$g_n=\frac{2^{-1/4}\,\eta\big(\tfrac{\tau}{2}\big)}{\eta(\tau)}\quad \text{even}\; n$$
There is [a modular equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchlaeflisModularForm.html) between $u=G_{25n}$ and $v = G_{n}$ given by,

$$\bigg(\frac{u}{v}\bigg)^3+\bigg(\frac{v}{u}\bigg)^3=2 \bigg(u^2v^2-\frac{1}{u^2v^2}\bigg)$$

or expanded out,
$$u^6 - 2 u^5 v^5 + 2 u v + v^6 = 0\tag1$$

---

Your post seeks $u=G_{625}$ if we are given $v = G_{25} = \phi$ which is the golden ratio. The sextic factors nicely as

$$(u-1)\big(u^5 - 5 \phi^3  (u^4 + u^3 + u^2 + u) - \phi^6\big)=0$$

Thus, the problem is to solve that quintic. Define,

$$w_1=\left(6+4\phi+3\times 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\phi} \right)^{1/5}+\left(6+4\phi-3\times 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\phi} \right)^{1/5}$$
$$w_2 = \left(12\phi+4\times 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\phi^{-1}} \right)^{1/5} +\left(12\phi-4\times 5^{1/4}\sqrt{\phi^{-1}} \right)^{1/5} $$

then the solution to $(1)$,
$$u^6 - 2 u^5 v^5 + 2 u v + v^6 = 0\tag1$$

is given by,
$$\begin{align}
u &= G_{625}=\phi^3+\phi^2 (w_1+w_2) = 22.180323\dots\\
v &= G_{25} = \phi = 1.618033\dots
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'd like to know how to solve the quintic.

Comment: @giuseppemancò: It's too long to describe step-by-step the method to solve solvable quintics.